# What is the better way to add pairs of strings into List<T>?

Tags: c#

I need to create List whete T is pair of strings.

I tryed to do that in most obvious way:

```
public struct rule {
    public string left, right;
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<rule> rules = new List<rule>();
        rules.Add(new rule("asd","asd"));
    }
}
```

I get that here needed constructor. And now i think - creating class just to put some strings into list sounds wrong.

Maybe here is any more simple way to do that?

Comment: @AshadShanto - note that a dictionary cannot contain duplicate keys. That might be ok, depending on what the OP is trying to.

Comment: try initializing like this `new rule { left = "asd", right = "asd" }`

Comment: @ben this will not work as those fields are not properties

Comment: @Vsevolod Goloviznin, it works.  i just did it to confirm in a new project.  They don't need to be properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from using a separate class (you're doing it wrong anyway), you can use a [`Tuple<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx). While using `KeyValuePair` is also an option here, logically it will not be correct as it represents a key with a corresponding value, which is not you want as I understand.

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> rules = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
rules.Add(Tuple.Create("aaa", "bbb"));
```

To repair you class approach you can do the following:

```
public struct rule {
    public string left, right;

    public rule(string left, string right) 
    {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

Or use auto-properties:

```
public class rule
{
    public string left {get;set;}
    publci string right {get;set;}
}
```

And then in your main method:

```
rules.Add(new rule {right ="asd", left = "asd"});
```

Comment: Thank you! Tuple is actually what i need.

Comment: But your class is actually better.

Comment: @InfernumDeus your struct with public members also works fine.  It's just a matter of preference and for simple structures I would probably do what you did. You can still use `rules.Add(new rule {right ="asd", left = "asd"});` in either case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with adding a class as you did above, but you could use a KeyValuePair

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> rules = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        rules.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("asd","asd"));
    }
}
```